# Aspnetcore 3.1 Date control and links sending differing formats

Tags: asp.net-core

I have been asked to look at a form on an aspnetcore 3.1 view, although this hopefully will change to aspnetcore 6.0 soon using a standard datetimepicker

```
<input class="datetimePicker" asp-for="SubmittedDateFrom" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyyTHH:mm}" />
```

This gives  ModelState values like "2022-11-01T18:27" and in the endpoint a value of {01/11/2022 18:27:00} and the date is preserved in the input.

There are various sort columns and paging that use a link to submit the data e.g.

```
<a asp-controller="Submissions"
                               asp-action="Index"
                               asp-route-SortField="Submitted"
                               asp-route-SortDir="@Model.SortDir"
                               asp-route-SortDirNext="@Model.SortDirNext"
                               asp-route-PageSize="@Model.PageSize"
                               asp-route-PageNumber="@Model.PageNumber"
                               asp-route-SubmittedDateFrom="@Model.SubmittedDateFrom"
                               asp-route-SubmittedDateTo="@Model.SubmittedDateTo">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Submitted)
                            </a>
```

The links call the same endpoint as the form submit.

When that link is clicked the ModelState values like "01/11/2022 18:27:00" and in the endpoint a value of {01/11/2022 18:27:00} and the date is lost in the input.

What am I looking at that is incorrect and how can I therefore fix this.  I have tried custom date validators, but that was not the solution.  I could hard tweak the ModelState to stop losing the input field value but that has to be wrong ad I have not manged to google something that explains this.

Note: The endpoint does not use a model its passed like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Submission>>> Index(string SortField = "Changed",
                            SortDirection SortDir = SortDirection.Descending,
                            SortDirection? SortDirNext = null,
                            int PageSize = 20,
                            int PageNumber = 1,
                            DateTime? SubmittedDateFrom = null,
                            DateTime? SubmittedDateTo = null)
```

Comment: If you look at the `modelState` it keeps the value by its `key` here datetime format comes in consideration. If you could debug you can see, string value can retain the value as expected while the date time format in your `anchor tag` and `input` doesn't recognize as same consequently the value doesn't kept. If you just try the same opetation using `form` it will works as expected. Main takeaway, is `ModelState` doesn't recognizes the key for anchor tag.

Comment: I was able to add en-GB to local and get rid of asp-format, then in the controller of the date was valid I converted the format in the ModelState Dictionary back to the datetime sort format used by the form submit before leaving the endpoint.  Not pretty but works for now.

Comment: Yes this one another reason as well. Mostly the reason was in format actually. I have tested every possible way.